# Is there a way to map two pandas.series to have the same values?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have these two long pandas.series with club names and want to have in both arrays the same names, so the first array will contain same club names as second array.

The first array:

`array(['Man United', 'Wolves','Man City',...], dtype=object)`

The second array:

`array(['Manchester United', 'Wolverhampton Wanderers','Manchester City',...], dtype=object)`

And I want to convert the names from the first array to the values from the second array. Any pythonic way of doing it?

Comment: Are the order of the clubs in the two series the same?

Comment: Do you want the first array to be equal to the second?

Comment: Do you want to change the values of your numpy arrays or the index names of your pandas series ?

Answer (score 0):

This is your initial array:

```
array_raw = ['Man United', 'Wolves', 'Man City']
```

You should first create a dictionary to map the raw and desired names of the clubs. Then you can use the dictionary 'dict_clubs' to obtain your desired array.

```
dict_clubs = {
     'Man United': 'Manchester United', 
     'Wolves': 'Wolverhampton Wanderers',
     'Man City': 'Manchester City'
}

result = [dict_clubs[x] for x in array_raw]
```

Output for result:

```
['Manchester United', 'Wolverhampton Wanderers', 'Manchester City']
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/users/13799930/caner-burc-baskaya - if you want you output to be a pandas series, you can use the map function:

```
original_series = pd.Series(['Man United', 'Wolves', 'Man City'])
dict_clubs = {
   'Man United': 'Manchester United', 
   'Wolves': 'Wolverhampton Wanderers',
   'Man City': 'Manchester City'
}
new_series = original_series.map(dict_clubs)
```

**Result**

```
new_series
Out[1]: 
0          Manchester United
1    Wolverhampton Wanderers
2            Manchester City
dtype: object
```